# VSTO Outlook: Define custom actions for contacts that satisfy some conditions

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-interop, office-addins

I would like to know if it is possible to associate some customs actions for contacts that satisfy some particular conditions. For example, if the contact has Linkedin profile specified, i would like to show it in its contact window. I don't know if contact window allows such type of customization or not. I have tried it but I haven't been able to achieve it. Could you confirm if such level of customization is possible?

Below an screenshot of the window I am interested in:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a form region in Outlook where you could display the required information about the contact item. Read more about Outlook form regions in the  [Walkthrough: Design an Outlook form region](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-designing-an-outlook-form-region?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp) article.

If that information is absent on the contact item you may prevent the form region from displaying, see [How to: Prevent Outlook from displaying a form region](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-prevent-outlook-from-displaying-a-form-region?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp).

Be aware, Outlook has already delivered a solution for integrating contacts with LinkedIn profiles. The `LinkedIn Outlook Connector` lets you add your LinkedIn account to Outlook and displays your connections in the Contacts section of the application. It also provides ways to add new connections through email, and keeps you up-to-date with the status updates of your connections. You can remove the add-in if you no longer want LinkedIn integrated with Outlook.

Read more about social connectors for Outlook in the [Outlook Social Connector 2013 provider reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/social-connector/outlook-social-connector-provider-reference) section.